# Bounds on degrees of minimal polynomials of infinite degree algebraic extension

Tags: polynomials, fields, field-extensions

If $E/F$ is algebraic  extension of finite degree $n$, then if $\alpha \in E$ is an element, then the degree of minial polynomial $m_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ is at most $n$. Even better, $\deg m_\alpha$ divides $n$. Are there some interesting bounds (with possibly some more conditions on $E,F,\alpha...$) on degree of $m_\alpha$ when the extension $E/F$ is of infinite degree?

Comment: In characteristic $0$, every finite extension has a primitive element. So if $[E:F]=\infty$, then you can find a sequence of $E_n\subset E$ with $[E_n:F]$ finite and going to $\infty$. Now take $E_n=F(\alpha_n)$, and the degree $m_{\alpha_n}\to\infty$. There are infinite extensions with interesting divisiblity properties, for example extensions such that for every $\alpha\in E$, the degree $m_\alpha$ is a power of some fixed prime $p$. But the power will grow.

Comment: There *are* purely inseparable extensions $E/F$ of infinite degree 
for which there exists a prime power $q$ such that
every $x \in E$ satisfies an equation $x^q = a$ for some $a \in F$.
For an example with $q=2$, take
$F = {\bf F}_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$
with the $x_n$ algebraically independent, and
$E = F(x_1^{1/2}, x_2^{1/2}, x_3^{1/2}, \ldots)$.